# Foreground service out of main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am quite a new-by in Android so be patient. I'm writing an app to tracking the smartphone using a foreground service in a Service class with notification to ensure the service will not be killed by the OS. Everything is fine except the Networkonmainthreadexception which arises when sending coordinates to the server. Inserting a policy.permitall I can solve the problem but I would like to use a separated thread instead. Nonetheless even starting the foreground service in a new thread (with start() method) I still receive the exception on networking.

I would leave Asynctask as a secondary choice due to long running service. I tried IntentService but the resulting code structure is not really the best for tracking with GPS.
Below the simple code to start the new thread.

```
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent rastreoIntent = new Intent(mContext, RastreoS.class );
                        rastreoIntent.setAction(RastreoS.ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
                        startService(rastreoIntent);
                    }
                };
                t.start();
```

So my question is: Can a foreground service run out of main thread? Are notifications in the UI binding the foreground service to the main thread even when started in a new thread?

Comment: Use the workmanager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 4):

The lifecycle methods (e.g. `onStartCommand()`) of `Service`, like other components on Android (e.g. `Activity`, `ContentProvider`, `BroadcastReceiver`), are always called by the system on your main thread. (You can optionally tell system to call your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` on another thread but that's it.)

Even if you are calling `startService()` on a worker thread, the actual start is scheduled asynchronously by the framework and will happen on the main thread later when it's free, so your `Service` lifecycle methods will still be called on main thread. To move the heavy work out of main thread, you will need to modify your code in your `Service` implementation.

Since you are using [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService), it is already creating worker threads for you, and you only need to ensure that your networking code is inside [`IntentService.onHandleIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) which will run on a worker thread.

Comment: Ok. Got it. It seems I 'll give IntentService a new try. Thanks for your time!